# How to split a long string which I want to print in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

```perl6
say "This is a very long line, and it seems it will not fit my screen, but alas, I don't know how to split it without getting an additional newline";
```

How to split the `"..."` into several lines (I mean in the code) without getting unneeded newlines in the output? I thought about `\` before newline, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know perl6, but can't you just write multiple string literals and concatenate them (`"foo" ~ "bar" ~ "baz"` or whatever perl6 uses)?

Comment: Certainly. I can even make two separate `say` statement. But I'd prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example works as a word quoted [here-doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Heredocs:_:to)

```
say qw:to<END>.join: ' ';
   This is a very long line, and it seems it will not fit my
   screen, but alas, I don't know how to split it without getting
   an additional newline
   END
```

Works in general if output is one line and input is a list of space separated words.

It's also possible to quote and join on lines:

```
say q:to<END>.lines.join: ' ';
   This is a very long line, and it seems it will not fit my
   screen, but alas, I don't know how to split it without
   getting an additional newline
   END
```

which preserves formatting within each line.

Comment: A perfect solution!

Comment: Seems that `lines.join;` without `: ' '` works better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is nothing better than concatenation:

```
say "This is a very long line, and it "
  ~ "seems it will not fit my screen, "
  ~ "but alas, I don't know how to split "
  ~ "it without getting an additional newline";
```

Comment: I'm afraid, that the `.` syntax for concatenation is from Perl 5 :)